# How to convert results of Model queries into xlsx using pandas in python?

Tags: python, sql, django, excel, pandas

I have a standart model's collection in my project like this one:

```
class Dimension(models.Model):
    dimension_id = MyCharField(max_length=1024, primary_key=True)
    name = MyCharField(max_length=255, null = False, unique=True)
    external_flg =  models.BooleanField(default = False)
    ext_owner = MyCharField(max_length=30, null = True)
    ext_table_name = MyCharField(max_length=30, null = True)
    ext_start_date_column_name = MyCharField(max_length=30, null = True)
    ext_end_date_column_name = MyCharField(max_length=30, null = True)
    ext_id_column_name = MyCharField(max_length=30, null = True)
    ext_name_column_name = MyCharField(max_length=30, null = True)
    ext_where_codition = MyCharField(max_length=512, null = True)
    def save(self):
        cnt =self.__class__.objects.filter(name=self.name).count()
        if cnt==0:
            if self.pk:
                super(Dimension, self).save()
            else:
                self.dimension_id = getUid()
                super(Dimension, self).save()
        else:
            raise DimensionUniqueError(self.name)
```

At this moment, I have to implement a button which will import data from our models to xlsx files and download it automatically on the client side.

We're planning to use pandas for sql to xlsx conversion, but I can't understand how to implement interaction with pandas for Models. For now I implemented it this way:

```
import pandas as ps

class Excel:
    def __init__(self, model_name):
        self.model_name = model_name
    def sql_to_xlsx():
        elements = self.model_name.objects.all()
        filter = self.request.GET.get('filter', None)

        if filter is not None:
            elements = elements.filter(filter_field=filter)
            columns = [desc[0] for desc in elements]
            data = [desc[1:] for desc in elements]
            df = ps.DataFrame(list(data), columns)
            writer = ps.ExcelWriter('converted.xlsx')
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='converted')
            return writer.save()

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        document = self.sql_to_xlsx()
        _file = open(document.filename, 'r')

        response = HttpResponse(_file, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % document.filename.split('/')[-1]  # Here will return a full path, that's why probably you will need a split to get only the filename
        add_never_cache_headers(response=response)  # To avoid download the same file with out of date data.
        return response
```

but it's not a correct logic what I would have expected to have. I have a feeling that it's not correct way to do.

Could you please help me to try out how to implement needed logic for our models?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need pandas to write to excel.

I would use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for writing to excel. Just following the example on their page should be good enough for you. You just have to loop through your model and use openpyxl to write to specific rows and columns that you want.