# How to get header and data from Models in Python?

Tags: python, django, model, xlsx, openpyxl

Following this example (for openpyxl):

```
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook

header = [u'Name', u'Email', u'Mobile', u'Current location',]
new_data = [[u'name1', u'email1@yahoo.com', 9929283421.0, u'xxxx'], [u'name2', u'email2@xyz.com', 9994191988.0, u'xxxx']]
wb = Workbook()

dest_filename = 'empty_book.xlsx'

ws1 = wb.active

ws1.title = "range names"

ws1.append(header)

for row in new_data:
    ws1.append(row)

wb.save(filename = dest_filename)
```

I have to split data that is going to be written into xlsx file on header and data itself.

So, how to extract header and data from Models in Django?

Comment: model_name.objects.all() would give you all of the data stored in the model right？ loop through this queryset and write data into the excel sheet. I don't know what's the question here? Also, I would appreciate if you could accept my answer to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30727207/how-to-convert-results-of-model-queries-into-xlsx-using-pandas-in-python)

Comment: It will give me rows in model, not a header. I need to get column names from the model as an array.

Comment: @Cheng the problem is that I need to write not only a data but header, which is compound of several fields: http://take.ms/MIA11

Comment: Is this question really about getting the column descriptions from Django models? This should be covered in the Django documentation but I suspect this is derived from the DB-API where the column description for a query is available from the cursor once the query has run.

Comment: Where are those headers stored? Please show your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the model's column name in database, do this:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    gender = models.CharField(db_column=u'column_name', max_length=10)
```

If you don't want to change the database's column name, use the verbose_name instead:

```
    gender = models.CharField(verbose_name=u'column_name', max_length=10)
```

Then, when you are ready to output the excel sheet:

```
for f in MyModel._meta.get_fields():
    print f.db_column  # or f.verbose_name
```

This is how you iterate through all of the columns in your model and get their name.

Why do you have to store the header name in a model? Why can't you store them statically in a list?

When you have a header that spans multiple columns, there is just no way to store them in a model.

Comment: No, my question is: having this table http://take.ms/MIA11 I need to reproduce this picture as a whole in Excel. This header shown on the screenshot is on the side of extJS frontend, and other information is pulled up from the backend side. I suppose that it's possible somehow to use __meta__ fields from the model, but don't quite understand how to implement it?

Comment: @paus please see my edit. This is gonna be my last try.